# If $f$ is analytic on an open and simply-connected subset of $\Bbb{C}$, and if $\cos{f}$ is constant, then must $f$ also be constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, analytic-functions, analyticity

I need help with the following question:

> Suppose $f$ is analytic on the open and simply connected space $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$. Must $f$ be a constant function if $\cos{f}$ is constant?

To me it seems natural that $f$ must be a constant function but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: $f'(z)\sin f(z)=0$. If $f$ is not a constant then we get $\sin f(z)=0$ except at countably many points (namely the zeros of $f'$). So .....

Comment: Aha! so either $f'=0$ which yields a constant function $f$ or $\sin{f}=0$ which yields $f=\pi+\pi k$ which also is constant. Thus $f$ must be constant, correct?

Answer (score 2):

If $\cos\circ f$ is $\{c\}$ and $\omega\in\Bbb C$ is such that $\cos\omega=c$, then the range of $f$ is a subset of$$\left\{\omega+2k\pi\,\middle|\,k\in\Bbb Z\right\}\cup\left\{-\omega+2k\pi\,\middle|\,k\in\Bbb Z\right\}.\tag1$$But $f$ is continuous and $\Omega$ is connected. So, $f(\Omega)$ is a connected subset of $(1)$. Can you take it from here?